# Как сохранить перенос строки из Textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mysql, asp.net

Есть форма блога для поста: Название статьи и тело поста.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostSave", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Headline, new { @id= "tw", cols = "40", rows = 
 "2" })
    <br />
    <br />
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.BodyText, new { @id = "bw", cols = "40", rows = 
"10" })

    <br />
    <br />

    <input id="Submit1" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Пост" />
}
```

Далее при нажатии кнопки вызывается метод в контроллере:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> PostSave(Post model)
    {
        db2.Post.Add(new Post { Headline = model.Headline, BodyText = 
 model.BodyText});
        await db2.SaveChangesAsync();

        return View("~/Views/Home/Blog.cshtml");
    }
```

Далее при загрузке DOM-дерева автоматом работает код JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function getData(data) {
    var url = "/api/Blog"
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        $("#idfirst").before('<div id="post" class="post">' +
            '<div id = "posthead" class= "posthead"></div >' +
            '<div id="postbody" class="postbody"></div></div >');

        $("#posthead").append('<p>' + data[6] + '</p>');
        $("#postbody").append('<p>' + data[7] + '</p>');
    });
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    getData();
})
```

Тут всё просто – перед блоком idfirst вставляем подготовленный блок со вложенными блоками для поста, со своими стилями. Тут всё работает. Но проблема в том, что он не сохраняет перенос на след строку.

Так я его вбил:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Так я его вижу: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените в JavaScript:

> `data[7]`

на:

> `data[7].split('\n').join('<br>')`

Либо на:

> `data[7].split('\n').join('</p><p>')`

---

**Дополнение:**

Хотя это не входит в ответ на вопрос, но всё же важно – как заметил пользователь **[Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy)**: в данных **[может оказаться произвольный код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3)** и поэтому для безопасности лучше записать так:

```
$("#posthead").append($('<p>').text(data[6].split('\n').join('<br>')));
$("#postbody").append($('<p>').text(data[7].split('\n').join('<br>')));
```

Либо же, если использовать CSS-свойство **[`white-space`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/white-space)** для `#posthead`и `#postbody` со значениями:

> `white-space: pre`, `white-space: pre-line` или `white-space: pre-wrap`

то данные из ответа сервера в соответствии с вышеупомянутой безопасностью можно вставлять и так:

```
$("#posthead").append($('<p>').text(data[6]));
$("#postbody").append($('<p>').text(data[7]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Перевод строки и так на месте, но стили ему не соответствуют.
Используй `white-space: pre-line` или `white-space: pre-wrap` для отображения.

> ```
> $("#posthead").append('<p>' + data[6] + '</p>');
> ```

Нельзя так делать - это [огромная дыра в безопасности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3), поскольку в данных может оказаться произвольный код.

Можно переписать так:

```
$("#posthead").append($('<p>').text(data[6]));
```

или использовать нормальный шаблонизатор, который умеет экранирование.

Comment: Спасибо.  вот это: white-space: pre-wrap; тоже работает. Возьму себе на вооружение. По поводу скрипта, согласен, все переделаю.

Comment: Кстати может подскажите где такие методы шаблонизированные на JavaScript взять. А то я почти всегда по бек-енду, с джаваскриптом сложновато у меня.

Comment: @FX_Sektor, dotJS, underscore/lodash и ещё куча всяких.